# .NET Core Update Permissions with Azure AD and Local DB

Tags: .net, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I have a .NET Core WebApp which logs the user in via the Azure AD. As soon as the user is logged in, I grab the Email address and check in my application database, which Role the user has.

Now the question is: Since the user can be locked (Db IsBlocked boolean field), I need to be able to update the user's permissions. Because the user remains logged in all the time (single-sign-on), do I need to check the user's permissions on each request? Meaning: On each request I query the DB for the permissions and update these accordingly ?

My concern is that this will result in a lot of requests to the DB, no ?
And also, can you update Claims ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion this is a balance of performance and security that you must choose.
I see at least 3 options here, each with their upsides and downsides:

1. Check the flag every request (Highest security, lowest performance)
2. Only check the flag on login (Lowest security, highest performance)
3. Mix of the two, store the last check time in the user's session and check from DB when the last check time is further than N minutes

Note when I say "highest security"/"lowest security", you really need to evaluate your scenarios and risks here and not checking a field like this on every request does not actually make your app insecure, unless the risks you want to prepare for include this scenario.
A lot of Microsoft's own applications (like within O365) rely on the access tokens generated by Azure AD that have a validity time of one hour.
So after disabling a user's login, it can take one hour for all the access to be taken away.

You can add claims to the user on your app's side, though you cannot modify the tokens sent by Azure AD (thanks to the digital signature they have).
But even if you can add claims, you still need to check the DB to check for updates to the flag.

Another approach that is similar to the third option I mentioned is to provide the front-end with a token (e.g. a JSON Web Token) that your app generates.
It has an expiry time so the front-end must refresh that token from your back-end at those intervals.
At that time you can check for blocked status and refuse to refresh the token.
By adjusting the token validity time, you can adjust the maximum available time a user could have before being blocked off.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, that is exactly what I was thinking as well, but thank you for the confirmation